# Can you add a filter (based upon a label) to the (TFS) Source Control Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am coming from a ClearCase (SCM) perspective but can you filter the (TFS) Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio based upon a label or exclude projects based upon a label?  Where I work they use TFS and have over a thousand projects.  It would certainly be nice to be able to only view active projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think labels do what you think they do. Labels are intended to "tag" a specific version of code. Like, for example, if you release version 3.0 of an application and you don't want to create a branch for it but want the ability to retrieve all of the source that went into it at a later time, you can label that version of the source.

So no, you can't filter by a label. There's no way to filter the source control explorer view other than by being denied read permissions.

Comment: What about using .tfignore? Or view only project's local to my machine?

Comment: `.tfignore` just controls what files are tracked by version control in your local workspace. Like I said, there is no way to filter the source control explorer. None. Zero.

Comment: That's too bad!  It seems such a basic feature.  I tried looking for extension but no luck.  Thanks for your help.